# Would these laptops be suitable for Blender 3.4?

Tags: rendering, fluid-simulation

So I am buying a new laptop for Blender and I want to make sure the specs are good enough and if anyone else has had experience with these specific laptops. In terms of what I need it for I am a bit of an all round artist but previously I have struggled with rendering and sims so that is why I am looking for an upgrade.

LENOVO LOQ (Intel® Core™ i7, RTX 4050, 512 GB SSD)
MSI Katana (Intel® Core™ i7, RTX 4060, 1 TB SSD)
Lenovo Legion 5 (AMD Ryzen™ 7, RTX 3060, 512 GB SSD)

Comment: Questions about hardware recommendations are off-topic here. See "What not to ask" here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic